# Tag Dispatch, why is wrong overload called?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits

In the code below the assertion does not fail, so how can `type_supports_deref_t<T>{})` construct anything else besides `true_type`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
struct ptr_traits {
    using supports_deref = std::false_type;
};

template <typename T>
struct ptr_traits<T*> {
    using supports_deref = std::true_type;
};

template <typename T>
struct ptr_traits<std::unique_ptr<T>> {
    using supports_deref = std::true_type;
};

template <typename T>
struct ptr_traits<std::shared_ptr<T>> {
    using supports_deref = std::true_type;
};

template <typename T>
using type_supports_deref_t = typename ptr_traits<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>::supports_deref;


template <typename T>
T& foo_impl(T&& t, std::false_type){
    std::cout<<"No-ptr  .. \n";
    return t;
}

template <typename T>
T& foo_impl(T&& t, std::true_type){
    std::cout<<"Ptr .. \n";
    return *t;
}

template <typename T>
T& foo(T&& t){
    return foo_impl(t, type_supports_deref_t<T>{}); 
}

struct Bar {
    int value = 10;
};


int main(){
    Bar* b1 = new Bar();
    foo(b1); // calls no ptr...
    std::cout<<std::boolalpha;
    std::cout<<(type_supports_deref_t<Bar*>::value); // returns true
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::true_type, decltype(type_supports_deref_t<Bar*>{})>::value, ""); // passes
    return 0;
}
```

Has the output:

```
No-ptr  .. 
true
```

Which in my mind only makes sense if the `false_type` overload is called, but the assertion does not fail, so what is going on?

**Edit:** Here is a working version for anyone that might be interested, it is a bit ugly..

```
template <typename T>
struct ptr_traits {
    using supports_deref = std::false_type;
};

template <typename T>
struct ptr_traits<T*> {
    using supports_deref = std::true_type;
};

template <typename T>
struct ptr_traits<std::unique_ptr<T>> {
    using supports_deref = std::true_type;
};

template <typename T>
struct ptr_traits<std::shared_ptr<T>> {
    using supports_deref = std::true_type;
};

template <typename T>
using type_supports_deref_t = typename ptr_traits<typename std::remove_reference<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>::type>::supports_deref;


template <typename T>
T& foo_impl(T&& t, std::false_type){
    std::cout<<"No-ptr  .. \n";
    return t;
}

template <typename T>
auto foo_impl(T&& t, std::true_type) -> decltype(*t){
    std::cout<<"Ptr .. \n";
    return *t;
}

template <typename T>
auto foo(T&& t) -> decltype(foo_impl(t, type_supports_deref_t<T>{})){
    return foo_impl(t, type_supports_deref_t<T>{}); 
}
```

Comment: In your `foo(b1)`, `T` is `Bar*&`.

Comment: Throw in `std::remove_reference` next to `std::remove_cv`. Once you do, you'll have a new problem: `foo_impl` overload for pointers tries to return `Bar` but is declared to return `Bar*&`

Comment: So the lesson here is to spam __PRETTY__FUNCTION__ :). @IgorTandetnik This is fun